# Help with $\sum_{w=0}^{n} {n \choose w}(q-1)^w=q^n$

Tags: combinatorics

This comes from coding theory by Freudenberger et al. p33

$\sum_{w=0}^{n} {n \choose w}(q-1)^w=q^n$

So my start:
$$\sum_{w=0}^{n} {n \choose w}\sum_{x=0}^{w}{w\choose x}(q)^x(-1)^{w-x}$$
now the first term could cancel 1 term from the inner sum using $\binom{n}{a}\binom{n-a}{b-a} = \binom{n}{b}\binom{b}{a}$ but I'm not sure this helps with the all the other terms. What's the quick solution that I don't see?

Comment: This is Newton's binomial formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

You have that

$$q^n=((q-1)+1)^n.$$